# Primefaces 4.0 Tree selection update in backing bean does not work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am having a primefaces Tree in a dialog. When I make selections in the Tree and click Add button, it adds all selections to a "p:selectManyMenu" in another panel. 
Code for the Dialog and Tree:

```
<h:form id="categoriesDialogForm">
<p:dialog id="categoriesDialog" header="Add a Category" widgetVar="categoriesDialogVar" closeOnEscape="true" height="500" resizable="false" >
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:tree id="categoriesTree" value="#{searchController.categoriesTree}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" style="width : auto;" selection="#{searchController.selectedCategories}" propagateSelectionDown="false" propagateSelectionUp="false">
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </p:column>                        
        </p:row>                        
    </p:panelGrid>
    <f:facet name="footer">                 
        <div align="center">
            <p:commandButton value="Add" style="font-size: 0.8em;" action="#{searchController.addCategory()}" update=":advSearchForm:subCatPanel"/>
        </div>
    </f:facet>            
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

So far it works fine. Now when I make selections in the ManyMenu and click remove button, it removes the selected categories from the backing bean "searchController.selectedCategories" and updates the dialog. Code for remove button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Remove" style="font-size : 0.9em;" action="#{searchController.removeCategory()}" update=":categoriesDialogForm:categoriesTree"></p:commandButton>
```

Code for removeCategory Java method

```
public void removeCategory() {   
 //Updating the selectedSubjectSet collection
 //removeSubjects is a Set for which the node selection should be removed
 for (String subToRemove : removeSubjects) {
        selectedSubjectSet.remove(subToRemove);
 }   

//Rebuilding the array of selections
//selectedSubjectSet is a Set whose selections in the Tree should remain
List<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (TreeNode t : selectedCategories) {
    if (selectedSubjectSet.contains(t.getData().toString())) {
        result.add(t);
    }
}
selectedCategories = result.toArray(new TreeNode[result.size()]);   
removeSubjects.clear();
}
```

But when I open the dialog again, the previous selections persist.
I am sure that the "searchController.selectedCategories" is updated but the selections in the Tree dont get updated. I also tried setting the "searchController.selectedCategories" value to null in remove button's action but the old values still persist. Not sure what is wrong. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion: try swapping form and dialog, and update the whole form instead

Comment: I take it you're not using a requestscoped bean?

Comment: @Jaqen: I am using ViewScoped bean

Comment: @Jaqen: Swapping form and dialog doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Try update the whole dialog: `<p:commandButton value="Remove" style="font-size : 0.9em;" action="#{searchController.removeCategory()}" update=":categoriesDialogForm:categoriesDialog"/>`

Comment: @rion18 : Thanks for the suggestion. Since I am updating the whole form, the Dialog gets updated anyways. I have tried it as well, doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Can you show us the `removeCategory` method?

Comment: I tried it and I came with a solution. For some reason the tree updates only if it's rebuilt. You need to reinitialize the `categoriesTree` tree... Could you try it?

Comment: @rion18 I have updated the question with my original code. I am posting the correct removeCategory() as an answer. We have to update both the selection array and also the Tree for it to reflect the changes. You had to re-initialize the Tree because there was a bug in the code, I did not do a setSelected(false) on subNode. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to update both the selection array and also the Tree for it to reflect the changes. The removeCategory() should have the following:

```
public void removeCategory() {   
  //Updating the selectedSubjectSet collection
  //removeSubjects is a Set for which the node selection should be removed
  for (String subToRemove : removeSubjects) {
      selectedSubjectSet.remove(subToRemove);
  }   

  //Rebuilding the array of selections
  //selectedSubjectSet is a Set whose selections in the Tree should remain
  List<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (TreeNode t : selectedCategories) {
     if (selectedSubjectSet.contains(t.getData().toString())) {
      result.add(t);
     }
  }
  selectedCategories = result.toArray(new TreeNode[result.size()]);   

  //Updating the Tree for selections
  //Need to iterate the Level 2 Nodes as well
  List<TreeNode> tree = categoriesTree.getChildren();        
    for (TreeNode node : tree) {
        String subject = (String) node.getData();
        if (removeSubjects.contains(subject)) {
            node.setSelected(false);
        }
        List<TreeNode> subTree = node.getChildren();
        for (TreeNode subNode : subTree) {
            subject = (String) subNode.getData();
            if (removeSubjects.contains(subject)) {
                subNode.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }

  removeSubjects.clear();
}
```