# p:tree selection set by bean not tracked in jsf site

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tree, selection

When I use a normal p:tree like

```
<p:dialog>
  <p:form>
    <p:tree value="aGetterMethod" selection="getAndSetMethods"/>
  </p:form>
</p:dialog>
```

And I select a parent node (so all children are also selected), and submit the form so save the changes to the backing bean, everything is fine (all selections are saved)

But when I reopen the dialog and try to unselect one child, it removes every selection made previously in this root. I figured out that the implicit set selections fur the children are not recognized as"selected" and therefore it tries to remove a nonnexistant selection which results in no selection.

Does anyone else fight with this issue?

I just want to get and set the selected nodes correctly when getting and selecting them.

Comment: After submitting the form, are the selected nodes still selected in the backing bean?

Comment: in the backing bean yes, but in the p:tree not (no selection at all). it works well until I sumit the form...

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740324/primefaces-4-0-tree-selection-update-in-backing-bean-does-not-work)... Can you try re-creating the tree and the selection?